# How to use Flutter GetX Sidebar

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

How can I implement the design in the image **(sidebar and navigation menu)** in Flutter using **GetX**? similarly to Tabs on the web. [image: Flutter Sidebar with GetX]

Comment: hi, any update?

Answer (score 1):

This is a example, maybe it can help you:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../routes/app_pages.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class SideBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 50.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Vakup",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.read_more),
            title: Text('Leer datos'),
            onTap: () {
              if (Get.currentRoute == Routes.HOME) {
                Get.back();
              } else {
                Get.toNamed(Routes.HOME);
              }
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.pets),
            title: Text('Registrar animal'),
            onTap: () {
              if (Get.currentRoute == Routes.NEWANIMAL) {
                Get.back();
              } else {
                Get.toNamed(Routes.NEWANIMAL);
              }
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.list_alt),
            title: Text('Lista movimientos'),
            onTap: () {
              if (Get.currentRoute == Routes.MOVEMENTS) {
                Get.back();
              } else {
                //Get.to
                Get.toNamed(Routes.MOVEMENTS);
              }
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.list),
            title: Text('Lista animales'),
            onTap: () {
              if (Get.currentRoute == Routes.LISTOFANIMALS) {
                Get.back();
              } else {
                Get.toNamed(Routes.LISTOFANIMALS);
              }
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
            title: Text('Grabar datos'),
            onTap: () {
              if (Get.currentRoute == Routes.GRABADO) {
                Get.back();
              } else {
                Get.toNamed(Routes.GRABADO);
              }
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.bluetooth),
            title: Text('Conexion BT'),
            onTap: () {
              if (Get.currentRoute == Routes.CONEXIONBT) {
                Get.back();
              } else {
                Get.toNamed(Routes.CONEXIONBT);
              }
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.picture_as_pdf),
            title: Text('Exportar Datos'),
            onTap: () {
              if (Get.currentRoute == Routes.EXPORT) {
                Get.back();
              } else {
                Get.toNamed(Routes.EXPORT);
              }
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.recent_actors_rounded),
            title: Text('Acerca de'),
            onTap: () {
              if (Get.currentRoute == Routes.ACERCA) {
                Get.back();
              } else {
                Get.toNamed(Routes.ACERCA);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the home part is:

```dart
import 'package:vakuprfid/app/modules/widgets/side_bar.dart';//import widget

class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: SideBar(),
        body: ...
      );
   }
}
```

This is the result: 
[image]

Comment: But what If I don't want to repaint Drawer again and again

Answer (score 1):

For the main content put all the different view into a **list** and put it into `PageView`. And create a custom navigator and put these two widget into a Row:

### Controller:

```dart
    class SettingsController extends GetxController {
      final PageController pageController =
          PageController(initialPage: 1, keepPage: true);
    }
```

### Sidebar:

```dart
    class MySideNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
      MySideNavigation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<MySideNavigation> createState() => _MySideNavigationState();
    }
    
    class _MySideNavigationState extends State<MySideNavigation> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final SettingsController c = Get.find();
        return NavigationRail(
          selectedIndex: c.selectedViewIndex.value,
          onDestinationSelected: (value) async {
            setState(() {
              c.selectedViewIndex(value);
              c.pageController.jumpToPage(
                value,
                // duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.decelerate
              );
            });
          },
          labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.selected,
          destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
            NavigationRailDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.map_outlined),
              selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.map_rounded),
              label: Text(
                'نقشه ها',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Vazir'),
              ),
            ),
            NavigationRailDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.map_outlined),
              selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.map_rounded),
              label: Text(
                'نقشه ها',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Vazir'),
              ),
            ),
            NavigationRailDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
              selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: Text(
                'پروفایل',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Vazir'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

### GotFatherView:

```dart
    class GodFatherView extends StatelessWidget {
          GodFatherView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
          final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
          final SettingsController c = Get.find();
          List<Widget> pages = [
            const KeepAlivePage(Page1()),
            KeepAlivePage(Page2()),
            const KeepAlivePage(Page3()),
          ];
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
                body: Row(
              children: [
                MySideNavigation(),
                Expanded(
                  child: PageView(
                    controller: c.pageController,
                    children: pages,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ));
          }
        }
```

tap on below link to open screenshot: I don't have enough reputation to post image :))))))

[Screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkDbE.png)

**Give a special attention to the sidebar navigator in **MySideNavigation** class:**

```dart
    NavigationRail(
          selectedIndex: c.selectedViewIndex.value,
          onDestinationSelected: (value) async {
            setState(() {
              c.pageController.jumpToPage(value);
            });
          },
```

When user tap on each `NavigationRailDestination` ,`onDestinationSelected` function will be called with an index. The index are representing the index of the destination view. Example: When user on `[Page1() -> index:0]` tab on the second `NavigationRailDestination` the index inside of function is `1`, so you can use the PageController to navigate into `[Page2() -> index:1]`.

## Attention, Attention, More Attention:

If you don't like to lose the state(I mean when u navigate to another view and back to previous view don't rebuild it again). Sometimes we need to keep the state of widget, we change something, write something into a text field and etc. If you don't wrap it with this widget all the data will be loosed(or you can save it through another way).

Wrap your widget with this Widget see the `GodFather` View I wrap all pages with `KeepAlivePage`, In this widget I extend State of the widget with 'AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin' and override its value `bool get wantKeepAlive => true;` .

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class KeepAlivePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const KeepAlivePage(this.child, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final child;

  @override
  State<KeepAlivePage> createState() => _KeepAlivePageState();
}

class _KeepAlivePageState extends State<KeepAlivePage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's easy，just let your right conent use GetMaterialApp and the route change is render right concent, then left sidler is a component warp your menuslider,
last control you left slider menuchange index.
show my code

````
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(dessignWidth, dessignHeight),
        builder: () => BarcodeKeyboardListener(
            onBarcodeScanned: (String codeValue) {},
            child: Material(
              child: MaterialApp(
                  localizationsDelegates: const [
                    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                  ],
                  supportedLocales: const [
                    Locale('zh', 'CH'),
                    Locale('en', 'US'),
                  ],
                  home: Row(
                    children: [
                      Material(
                        child: SliderMenu(),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          child: GetMaterialApp(
                              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                              enableLog: true,
                              navigatorKey: Get.key,
                              routingCallback: RouteChangeMiddleWare.observer,
                              logWriterCallback: Logger.write,
                              initialRoute: AppPages.INITIAL,
                              getPages: AppPages.routes,
                              unknownRoute: AppPages.unknownRoute,
                              builder: EasyLoading.init(),
                              onInit: () =>
                                  {logger.v('Global.CONFIG', AppConfig)}))
                    ],
                  )),
            )));
  }```
hope to help you;
````

Comment: How can I navigator to another page in SliderMenu() ? Get.toName and Get.offAndToNamed not looks good